# IntelliJ 12.1.2, files not opening in the window

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I reinstalled intellij 12.1.2 and now my project opens in the explorer, however when I click on my grails file, the file do not open up in the window. I tried to drag and drop but still no luck, anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: Update to 12.1.4, check [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446) for exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this kind of issue happens you should check [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446) for exceptions.

It's also a good idea to ensure that you are running the [latest IDE version](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).

Comment: new to intellij, thanks for the advice, will definately keep in mind